# Align an Icon and Feed Heading

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to align an image with an , and I cannot get the heading to wrap around the image icon. I have a screen cap here: http://instagram.com/p/YNGBzrtAs8/

My CSS code is a mess because I keep trying everything, and it's getting messy. Here is the current mess state:

```
#deck-sub .news-feed { float: left; width: 90%; padding: 5%; margin: 0 0 15px 0; }
    #deck-sub h1 { background: none; font: bold 2.0em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #006586; margin: 0 0 -8px 0; }
    #deck-sub .news-feed h2 a {  color: #006586; text-decoration: none; font-size: 1.2em !important; margin: -33px 0 0 0;}
    #deck-sub .news-feed ul {vertical-align: middle !important; background: none; padding: 5px 0 0 0; list-style: none; }
    #deck-sub .news-feed ul li { vertical-align: middle !important; width: 100%; padding: 5px 0 5px 0; margin: 5px 0 0 0;}
    #deck-sub .news-feed ul li a  { vertical-align: middle !important; width: 100%; font: 0.8em/1.1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #555 !important; text-decoration: none; padding: 0px 0 0 0; margin: -5px 0 0 0; }
    #deck-sub .news-feed ul li a:hover { background: none; color: #009fc7 !important; }
    #deck-sub .new-feed ul li img {  vertical-align: middle !important;  }
    #deck-sub .sfnewsListItem { vertical-align: middle !important; background: #ccc; }
    #deck-sub .sfnewsMetaInfo { vertical-align: middle !important; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; background: #444;}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have run into this before, but my tricks are not working in this case. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can we have the HTML please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by get the heading to wrap around...but I assume you want the image and the title to be beside eachother? vertical-align I don't believe works awesomely for this.

The best option is to remove the icon as an  and instead put it into the CSS as a background image.  Doing that gives you the ability to position it to the pixel.

It'd also let you sprite those two news\event icons into a single file to serve less resources.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Cheers!
Steve